# What is the correct way to map InternalResourceViewResolver and TilesViewResolver in webmvc.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have to integrate two projects. 
one project is having all jsp file and another project with jspx.

Below are the file entries in webmvc-configuration file.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
     <property name="order" value="1"/>     
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" 
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" 
     value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
    <property name="viewNames">
        <list>
            <value>list.jspx</value>
            <value>menu.jspx</value>
            <value>show.jspx</value>
            <value>create.jspx</value>
            <value>update.jspx</value>
         </list>
    </property>
    <property name="order" value="0"/>
</bean>


<!-- Tiles configuration -->
<bean id="tilesConfigurer" 
 class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles-definitions.xml</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/admin/layouts/layouts.xml</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/admin/views/**/views.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The error which i am getting is that it cannot locate the .jspx file.

url "settings/surveyDefinitions/list"

```
14:12:26.888 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'settings/surveyDefinitions/list'
14:12:26.888 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'settings/surveyDefinitions/list'; URL [settings/surveyDefinitions/list.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'hifi-web-dispatcher'
14:12:26.888 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Added model object 'modelAndView' of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView] to request in view with name 'settings/surveyDefinitions/list'
14:12:26.888 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Added model object 'org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.modelAndView' of type [org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult] to request in view with name 'settings/surveyDefinitions/list'
14:12:26.888 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Added model object 'surveyDefinitions' of type [java.util.LinkedHashSet] to request in view with name 'settings/surveyDefinitions/list'
14:12:26.888 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Added model object 'maxPages' of type [java.lang.Integer] to request in view with name 'settings/surveyDefinitions/list'
14:12:26.888 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Forwarding to resource [settings/surveyDefinitions/list.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'settings/surveyDefinitions/list'
```

it is taking as `settings/surveyDefinitions/list.jsp` not `list.jspx`.
any idea or suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out i was doing it wrong and the way i did is,

```
<bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
    <property name="order" value="0"/>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
</bean>

    <!-- Tiles configuration -->
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles-definitions.xml</value>
                <value>/WEB-INF/admin/layouts/layouts.xml</value>
                <value>/WEB-INF/admin/views/**/views.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```